# Can I create an Eclipse Project that produces multiple executable Jars?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, executable-jar

I have a project with a library JAR and a set of applications. Right now the applications (all 5 of them) are in a single project. These tools each have one or two classes, they run from the command line with one exception.  Even the GUI tool has only about 8 classes. I am struggling with how best to structure this in Eclipse.

I have seen that I can use maven-shade to create multiple executable JARs from one project. I would need to convert the project to Maven, but I assume that is not a big problem.

I can create a separate project for each tool. This seems like overkill to have several projects with one or two classes in each.

Additionally, both of these solutions will leave me with either a bare class file or a JAR plus the dependent library JAR. Not ideal for deployment.

Before I pick one of these, I thought I would ask here if there is a different approach that I am missing for packaging these tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse, Export --> Archive file, You can select/deselect what classes you want to export into your Jar File

Comment: Can you make an executable jar using `Export --> Archive` ?

Comment: I just ran through the process and yes you can specify a main class for the Jar.

Comment: This works pretty well. Anyone know of a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but You could/need to create using Maven, and for each build building jar you need to set the main Class.
Checkout the documentation of Maven. 
I think You could to the same with Gradle, but not sure.

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/attached-jar.html

Comment: For Maven, the app-assembler plugin allows for building multiple launch scripts for a single artifact.